# Sorting 4 numbers from least to greatest using JOptionPane

Tags: java, sorting, joptionpane

I forgot the code to use to sort 4 numbers using the easiest method. I've searched everywhere for this code and I still can't find it.

This is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SortingNumbers
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String input;
double number1, number2, number3, number4, sort;
int lowest, middle1, middle2, highest

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number");
number1 = Double.parseDouble(input);

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second numebr");
number2 = Double.parseDouble(input);

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter third number");
number3 = Double.parseDouble(input);

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter fourth number");
number4 = Double.parseDouble(input);





 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sort);

  System.exit(0);
  }
 }
```

Comment: And the question is....

Comment: What is the code to sort number1-number4 least to greatest?

sort = (this code) ;

Comment: sort = Arrays.sort() ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quick and easy way to sort numbers, I suggest storing the values in an appropriate Array, and calling Arrays.sort();

eg:

```
// create the array and put values in it
Double[] x = new Double[4];
x[0] = number1;
x[1] = number2;
x[2] = number3;
x[3] = number4;

// sort the values lowest -> highest
Arrays.sort(x);
// print out each value (but really, you can do anything here)
for (Double y : x) {
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing library function sort from Arrays:

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(n1); list.add(n2); list.add(n3); list.add(n4);
Arrays.sort(list);
```

Here is the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) documentation.